# Multiprocessing.Lock not available in Python run in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an object that caches some AWS SSM Parameters. I wanted to implement this class multiprocessor safe. But in an AWS Lambda Python environment `/dev/shm/` is not available so I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

The error occurs on the line where the `Lock` is initialized.
Here is the code for the cache class:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock


class CachedRetriever:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """
    CachedRetriever uses a local dictionary cache to store results.
    If there is a cache hit the result is immediately returned.
    The Cache never expires and does not have a limited size.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.__cache = {}
        self.__cache_lock = Lock()

    def cached_get(self, key: str, function, **kwargs):
        """
        Get using the cache or store it in the cache.
        :param key: The key of the cached value
        :param function: The function which has to be executed
        :param kwargs: The arguments which will be used by the function
        :return:
        """
        if key not in self.__cache:
            with self.__cache_lock:
                if key not in self.__cache:
                    self.__cache[key] = function(**kwargs)

        return self.__cache[key]
```

What is a multiprocessing safe way to implement this class that can run using the limited multiprocessing types in aws python?

See for additional information:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=219962

Comment: In your question you write `I wanted to implement this class multithreaded safe`

This should be multi process safe I assume?

Comment: I do  have existing code that uses file locking (fcntl) to ensure that a certain executable is only executed once.

This code in combination with inotify might allow to create an interprocess mutex without /dev/shm except if file locking also't depend on /dev/shm, but I don't think so.

If you don't get any other answers can post what I have and try to suggest how to enhance the code.

Comment: what exact line of your code raises the NotImplementedError?

Tro to run your code without lock, in a test environment just to show, that everything else would be working as soon as you implemented another Lock.

In your test case you would write the code such to be sure, that no race conditions or concurrent accesses occur. (one proc reading while the other modifies)

Comment: I changed my question to answer your questions.